# Move LVM from BusyBox based NAS (ZyXEL) to Debian

Tags: lvm

I am trying to move a single drive from a BusyBox based NAS (ZyXEL 542) to a Debian Stable server. The drive was configured as a single drive in the NAS.

I could see in the NAS that the drive appeared to be mounted using an LVM (as it was a single drive) -

[image]

Following this guide - https://access.redhat.com/solutions/4123 I unmounted all 3 partitions, marked the VG as inactive and exported it.  When attaching it to the Debian instance, when running *lsblk*, all it returns is the single device (sdb) with no partitions.

fdisk and parted do not show any other partitions -

[image]

Using LVM tools, I get various errors/messages indicating nothing is found -

pvscan - *No matching physical volumes found*

vgscan ouput -

[image]

pvdisplay /dev/sdb - *Device is partitioned* And no other devices found if you try partition numbers.

Using Testdisk I was able to get it to show the various partitions on the disk -

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am not sure exactly how to interpret the first two messages, but the main screen clearly shows 3 partitions, although as a RAID type which I was not expecting.

I have tried to use mdadm to examine the drive and to assemble and scan it, this also does not work.

For example, trying to run - *sudo mdadm --examine /dev/sdb* returns

```
mdadm: No md superblock detected on /dev/sdb.
```

Running a deeper scan using Testdisk DOES show up an LVM partition (this is still running since it is a 10TB disk) -

[image]

Testdisk also indicates that it has not implemented support for the filesystem yet.

At this point I am not sure where to go from here.  Do I need to wait for the deeper scan to complete before I can access the LVM partition to at least try and copy data out?  I was hoping I could get this mounted on the Debian instance as-is.

Thanks!

Comment: Once the testdisk scan of the disk finished, there were a LOT of odd FAT16 partitions towards the end of the disk, but the one highlighted below appears to have my data in it, and I have been able to copy some out.

Comment: ![Testdisk Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/vIzDGOx.png).